# creating a new mysql table using JAVA

Tags: java, mysql

I'm trying to create a table similar to a ready table I created before (a template, if you will) where the only variable should be the table name.

This is what I've tried so far:
I exported the template table to mysql code and copied the code to a preparedStatement object as such:

```
createNewLineTableStatement = constantLink.prepareStatement("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ? (" +
                    "  `index` int(5) NOT NULL," +
                    "  `station` int(5) NOT NULL," +
                    "  PRIMARY KEY (`index`)," +
                    "  UNIQUE KEY `station` (`station`)" +
                    ") ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;\");");
```

Than I try to execute the code by calling the following function:

```
private static boolean createNewLineTable(String tableName) throws SQLException{
    createNewLineTableStatement.setString(1, tableName);
    if (createNewLineTableStatement.executeUpdate() == Statement.EXECUTE_FAILED)
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

But I'm getting a syntax error exception:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''line_37_var_1' (  `index` int(5) NOT NULL,  `station` int(5) NOT NULL,  PRIMARY' at line 1
```

How can I fix the code? OR is there a cleaner, better way to do the same thing? Maybe creating a script with a user variable? I thought of that but I've never used .sql script before.

Comment: are you sure you can use the column with name "index".  Thought it is keyword.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. I originally created the template table using phpmyadmin and it was created without a hitch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem 1: You can't use a prepared statement parameter as the table name.

Problem 2: You have an unmatched paren and extra characters `");`at the end of your statement.

Your query string should look something like:

```
String query = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `" + tableName + "` (" +
    "  `index` int(5) NOT NULL," +
    "  `station` int(5) NOT NULL," +
    "  PRIMARY KEY (`index`)," +
    "  UNIQUE KEY `station` (`station`)" +
    ") ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci";
```

Answer (score 0):

by design, TableName and ColumnNames cannot be parameterized.

If you are scared about `SQL Injection`, create a custom function to check for malicious tableName. It is safe if the value comes inside of your application.

Then concatenate it in the string, *add backtick for first level of defense :D*

```
String tableName = "Your tableName";
String query = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `" + tableName + "` (" +
                    "  `index` int(5) NOT NULL," +
                    "  `station` int(5) NOT NULL," +
                    "  PRIMARY KEY (`index`)," +
                    "  UNIQUE KEY `station` (`station`)" +
                    ") ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci";
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing Table name and i think that "?" shouldn't be there.

I will be something like

```
"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS YOURTABLE" + the following code
```